# Strange Android memory consumption before even before first Activity starts

Tags: java, android, memory, dalvik

I observed a strange behavior of Android just before my app starts. It seems that a lot of memory is allocated even before my app starts doing something. The GC tells me that only 90% percent of the heap are free. And at the moment the app starts even before the "onCreate" of my first activity has been called the JVM has only 4% free memory left. What happend here, and how can I prevent this from happening, because with only 4% of 64MB heap left my app cant operate.

```
03-09 21:00:16.517 1684-2249/? D/k: Processing package: de.ponysoft.backhome
03-09 21:00:16.549 1684-1684/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK com.google.android.gms
03-09 21:00:16.587 1524-1524/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
03-09 21:00:16.587 1524-1524/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
03-09 21:00:16.684 1684-2252/? I/PeopleContactsSync: triggerPendingContactsCleanup: no accounts
03-09 21:00:16.699 1684-2249/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package de.ponysoft.backhome:3. Hash: 8514543eb70ddc4389765ad8baac5ba8cab5be6e67d756a46e474b3d85051122
03-09 21:00:16.700 1684-2249/? D/k: Found info for package de.ponysoft.backhome in db.
03-09 21:00:17.375 346-366/? W/VoiceInteractionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0
03-09 21:00:17.850 346-377/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12467(807KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(81KB) LOS objects, 26% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 13.482ms total 1.768s
03-09 21:00:17.925 1684-1795/? I/Icing: Indexing 6F97C46050CD983C7FFCEB53F6194D5AB9C51AB5 from com.google.android.gms
03-09 21:00:17.972 2224-2224/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-09 21:00:18.184 1684-1795/? I/Icing: Indexing done 6F97C46050CD983C7FFCEB53F6194D5AB9C51AB5
03-09 21:00:19.720 2260-2260/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
03-09 21:00:20.299 2260-2260/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
03-09 21:00:20.302 2260-2260/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
03-09 21:00:20.553 2260-2260/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-09 21:00:20.608 346-1270/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=de.ponysoft.backhome/.InitActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
03-09 21:00:20.780 2260-2260/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-09 21:00:20.968 2270-2270/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-09 21:00:21.005 346-930/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc de.ponysoft.backhome for activity de.ponysoft.backhome/.InitActivity: pid=2270 uid=10057 gids={50057, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=armeabi-v7a
03-09 21:00:21.200 69-69/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 706(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 90% free, 110KB/1134KB, paused 21.161ms total 146.487ms
03-09 21:00:21.261 346-367/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 1127:com.android.music/u0a36 (adj 15): empty for 1801s
03-09 21:00:21.336 346-411/? W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10036/pid_1127/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
03-09 21:00:21.388 69-69/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(240B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 90% free, 110KB/1134KB, paused 1.021ms total 179.966ms
03-09 21:00:21.491 69-69/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(160B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 90% free, 110KB/1134KB, paused 872us total 96.457ms
03-09 21:00:22.586 2270-2286/? I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
03-09 21:00:22.662 2270-2270/? D/InitActivity: onCreate
03-09 21:00:22.817 2270-2270/? D/InitActivity: onStart
```

This high memory consuption also causes my app to crash with an OOM Exception

```
03-09 21:00:31.543 2270-2287/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 65MB to 64MB
03-09 21:00:31.543 2270-2287/? I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 28(1312B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 61MB/64MB, paused 1.088ms total 25.705ms
03-09 21:00:31.613 2270-2287/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 65MB to 64MB
03-09 21:00:31.613 2270-2287/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 61MB/64MB, paused 2.256ms total 67.540ms
03-09 21:00:31.613 2270-2287/? I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8MB allocation
03-09 21:00:31.676 2270-2287/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 65MB to 64MB
03-09 21:00:31.676 2270-2287/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 61MB/64MB, paused 1.077ms total 61.122ms
03-09 21:00:31.677 2270-2287/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 9060076 byte allocation with 2786284 free bytes and 2MB until OOM"
03-09 21:00:31.678 2270-2287/? D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
03-09 21:00:31.696 2270-2287/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                 Process: de.ponysoft.backhome, PID: 2270
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9060076 byte allocation with 2786284 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
                                                     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:467)
                                                     at de.ponysoft.backhome.async.AsyncLoadImages.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(AsyncLoadImages.java:186)
                                                     at de.ponysoft.backhome.async.AsyncLoadImages.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImages.java:91)
                                                     at de.ponysoft.backhome.async.AsyncLoadImages.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImages.java:27)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-09 21:00:31.702 346-1507/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity de.ponysoft.backhome/.InitActivity
03-09 21:00:31.769 55-55/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 55: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

I ran this one in the emulator with API 21. But I also observed this behavior on older phones like the Samsung Galaxy S2. My release version of my app is 3.7MB in total. All assets are Full-HD. On newer phones there is no memory problem, only on older phones.

Comment: You would like to know how to overcome this by changing the settings for the virtual device? Or do you want to know where you can save some CPU power? It is not clear what exactly you seek. Could you please explain a bit more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: On older phones you have less memory and your full hd asset will take a much larger percentage of it.  I see you are decoding a bunch of bitmaps-  my guess is those devices don't have enough room to preload them all.  Really you should never preload bitmaps without using a cache like LRUCache to control how much memory is used.

Comment: @JernejK I would like to know what is going on at the time the app is initiated and why the whole memory is allocated, because my app hasn't done anything at that point

Comment: @GabeSechan So what would be the best practice here ? (aBout laoding the images), I already use the code to load large bitmaps efficiently (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) but I still get the OOM Exception. Anyway the heap size is 64MB and at the point where the Exception arises it tries to allocate 9MB so I don't think this is that much. I see two staring point on how to overcome this exception, First understating why so much memory is allocated before the start and fix this, or secondly improve loading of the images

Comment: 9MB out of 64 MB is 15% of your total memory.  That's a lot.  And remember, memory use is cumulative.  The best practice is not to load all images at the beginning of your app and to load images through an LRUCache so that you don't use more than a fixed amount of memory on images (you can change the fixed amount based on the device so better phones can use a bigger cache).

Comment: @GabeSechan you are right, did thought about that before I started writing, sry. I'll try the LRUCache I did'nt knew that concept. I'll let you know how it worked out. Thank you very much :-)